# Promise within a function got error of is not a function error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I try to print insertion of 10 one by one into an array

```
const obj = []
const delay = (timer, num) => setTimeout(() => Promise.resolve(num), timer)

_.times(10).map(o => {

  delay(1000, o).then(num => console.log(obj.push(num)))

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/287b4daz/

But I got delay.then is not a function error? or I don't even need to use Promise here since setTimeout itself is already a promise?

Comment: your delay function returns the setTimeout return value, which isn't a promise ... you need to nest the setTimeout inside a Promise instead ... `const delay = (timer, num) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timer, num))`

Comment: `setTimeout()` returns a timer reference...no a promise.

Comment: `setTimeout itself is already a promise` - no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complaining that `deplay(...).then` is not a function - that `deplay` doesn't return a Promise. You need to use the Promise constructor instead of `Promise.resolve`:

(also, changing `deplay` to `delay`:)

```js
const obj = []
const delay = (timer, num) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(num), timer))
_.times(10).map(o => {
  delay(1000, o).then(num => console.log(obj.push(num)))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to chain them together so each one waits for the previous one to resolve before running, use `.reduce`:

```js
const obj = []
const delay = (timer, num) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(num), timer));
Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i + 1)
  .reduce((lastPromise, o) => (
    lastPromise
      .then(() => delay(1000, o))
      .then(num => console.log(obj.push(num)))
  ), Promise.resolve())
```

Comment: `setTimeout(() => resolve(num), timer)` ... or `setTimeout(resolve, timer, num)` for the cool kids :p

Comment: if you rewrite the code, then, of course ... just don't use `.then` if you don't use `Promise` - my suggestion was the setTimeout portion of the code

Comment: this doesn't print one by one

Comment: @AlisaF.Kennedy If you want to be able to call `then` on the result, then you *do* need a Promise, he was just suggesting an alternate way of passing the arguments

Comment: your original code is flawed - you aren't `chaining` the promises at all

Comment: if you want the results to be sequentially one second apart, then Promises will make it very easy

Comment: either way, I can't make it like [1], a second later, [1,2], after a second later [1,2,3] and so on.. @JaromandaX can you show some code? I don't see without Promise it's doable.

Comment: it is doable without promises, just a little more complex. Promises make asynchronous code easier - but the same can be done using callbacks if you want to make it in series

Comment: @AlisaF.Kennedy You can chain the promises together with `.reduce` too, see edit

Comment: and no need for lodash in that case :p (or the first case either to be clear)

Answer (score 0):

To print one by one, assuming you mean every second (according to comment in answer)

```js
    const obj = []
    const delay = (timer, num) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timer, num));
    let p = Promise.resolve();
    _.times(10).map(o => {

        p = p
        .then(() => delay(1000, o))
        .then(num => console.log((obj.push(num+1), obj+'')));
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Note ... `push(num+1)` if you want `1`, `1,2` etc otherwise it's `0`, `0,1` etc

Note 2: `console.log(x.push(y))` logs the **new length of x**, not the array x - which is why I put `console.log((obj.push(num+1), obj+''))` note the `()` inside, with a `,` operator so that the output is `obj+''`

really, to be clear, you should write it

```
    const obj = []
    const delay = (timer, num) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timer, num));
    let p = Promise.resolve();
    _.times(10).map(o => {
        p = p
        .then(() => delay(1000, o))
        .then(num => {
            obj.push(num+1);
            console.log(obj.join(','))
        });
    })
```

the other thing to point out is that `.map` is the wrong thing to use here, as `.map` is used to map an array to a new array of values - as you are dealing with asynchronous code, the resulting array will be, at best an array of undefined, or an array of Promises - but since you aren't assigning the result of `.map` to anything, then this point is pretty moot